# Java8: Using Function::identity in Collectors.toMap(..) creates an argument mismatch error

Tags: java, generics, java-stream, collectors

Given this simple Person POJO:

```
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Person(String id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I would like to collect a `Map<String, Person>` where the key is the `id` of the Person.

I have tried to implement it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CollectorMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Person("312", "John"));
        list.add(new Person("454", "Alice"));
        list.add(new Person("712", "Bob"));

        Map<String, Person> map = list.stream()
               .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function::identity) // COMPILE ERROR
               );
        System.out.println(map.size());
    }
}
```

But I get a compile error:

```
CollectorMain.java:[14,41] no suitable method found for toMap(Person::getId,Function::identity)
    method java.util.stream.Collectors.<T,K,U>toMap(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>,java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,U
        (argument mismatch; incompatible parameter types in method reference))
    method java.util.stream.Collectors.<T,K,U>toMap(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>,java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends U>,java.util.function.BinaryOperator<U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method java.util.stream.Collectors.<T,K,U,M>toMap(java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends K>,java.util.function.Function<? super T,? extends U>,java.util.function.BinaryOperator<U>,java.util.function.Supplier<M>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T,K,U,M
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
```

---

As a solution I can replace `Function::identity` with this lambda `p -> p` like this:

```
Map<String, Person> map = list.stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, p -> p)
    );
```

Is there a possibility to use `Function::identity` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not use a method reference. You should use `Function.identity()`.

If you use a method reference, you're basically trying to pass a `Supplier<Function<T, T>>`.

```
Map<String, Person> map = list.stream().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity())
);
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `Function.identity()` worked? I was expecting `p -> Function.identity(p)` ?

Comment: `Function.identity()` basically returns `p -> p`